# Kafka container don't start because the docker Warning : Published ports are discarded when using host network mode

Tags: java, docker, networking, apache-kafka, containers

I have some Kafka docker tests on jenkins working with some different SO images, but if I tried to execute this in local fails,because of warning publish ports are discarded wh host net mode.
In my java classes structure I have a KafkaContainer class that extends DockerContainer class with this method:

```
private static String[] getKafkaConfigs(){
   return new String[]{"--network=host"};
 }
```

After that I run that Kafka instance with ZookeperContainer, this ZookeperContainer as well, it have got the same method config:

```
return new String[]{"--network=host"};
```

The ports are the Kafka (9092) and zookeper(2181) commons ports.
In my port 8080, the localhost server running.
Any idea, how can I fix it to execute this in a localhost environment.

Thank you

Comment: Are you using these? https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/kafka/ Or why do you want host networking over Docker-in-Docker?

Comment: Nop, the test is build to execute inside a container for specific Operative Systems (based in Linux), sorry if I say any mistakes, I don't have much knowledge of container and dockers, but I've tried to read something ralated to use a bridge instead use --net=host.Do you have any idea?

Comment: _test is build to execute inside a container_ -- Exactly, so you'd use Docker-in-Docker (otherwise known as DinD) [mentioned here](https://www.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/continuous_integration/dind_patterns/), where your 8080 service should also be containerized, so you don't need host networking. But since you are using Java, you should be able to use that library fine [via JUnit](https://www.testcontainers.org/quickstart/junit_5_quickstart/),

Comment: The related about testcontainers web is a good point but here I have the feeling the solution is about configuration issue maybe related to change this configuration to execute in local:  --network=host but I don't know how. I've tried changing to --ip:127.0.0.1 or adding that to the ExecStart in /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker.service but it dosen't work yet

Comment: So, first things first, host networking isn't going to prevent Kafka or Zookeeper from starting, so there's some other issue there.

Answer (score 0):

Changing to PODMAN solved the problem. I've read some articles like https://computingforgeeks.com/using-podman-and-libpod-to-run-docker-containers/
and others.
It's an excellent alternative and complete CLI compatibility with Docker.
BTW, if anyone has a better solution with docker native, please don't hesitate to post it, thank you.